# The simplest file format with image and text layers for C++ parser

Tags: c++, parsing, layer, file-format, psd

I'm searching for the file format that is the simplest and has features:

1. layers with images (with transparency)
2. layers with texts (I need only font name, color, size, position and text content itself)

I know that .psd has that features, but it's very complicated, I didn't found nice parser for it and it has many many features that I don't need at all but I would have to handle them to parse the file.

The perfect solution would be the file format that is easy to create/export from Photoshop (e.g. tif, but it doesn't have text layers).

Another pro for file format would be existing (e.g. LGPL), simple (!) C/C++ parser class for it.

Do you know any such file format?

Comment: I would also suggest SVG

Comment: But it's not an only vector file format? I want to work with rasterized images.